# Why does /etc/resolv.conf not update when I change my DNS?

Tags: 16.04, networking, dns

I have been trying to change my dns to `8.8.8.8` `8.8.4.4` but don't seem to be able to do it.

In `/etc/resolv.conf` I have

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

In `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` I added

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

and reloaded with `sudo resolvconf -u`

but nothing changes in `/etc/resolv.conf`

If I misspell something in `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` for example adding `ameserver 8.8.8.8` and reloading `cat /etc/resolv.conf` now shows.

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.0.1
ameserver 8.8.8.8
```

What should I be doing to change the dns and how can I check if it has worked?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To expand on the other answer here, and to clear up some confusions here, if you are using Network Manager to manage your connections, it also includes a small version of dnsmasq.  This is what the 127.* address is in your resolv.conf - the IP address of localhost, where dnsmasq has bound to.

Network Manager, when configured with the DNS servers, will tell dnsmasq what DNS servers to relay requests to.

If you set 8.8.8.8 as your DNS server in Network Manager's settings, dnsmasq will forward all requests that aren't cached to 8.8.8.8 for actual resolving, while your computer sends DNS requests directly to dnsmasq for handling.

Confusing, I know, but you can't rely on resolv.conf to show the DNS servers in use when you are using Network Manager to manage the connections.

Comment: This really answered my questions, I saw a lot of posts online about how `/etc/resolv.conf` contains your dns server but it wasn't changing when I went through the usual methods.

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and I found this:
> Netplan is the default network management tool on Ubuntu 18.04, replacing the /etc/resolv. conf and /etc/network/interfaces configuration files that have been used to configure the network in the previous Ubuntu versions
systemd-resolved is a service that provides DNS name resolution to local services and applications and it can be configured with Netplan, the default network management tool on Ubuntu 18.04
To check status: `systemd-resolve --status | grep 'DNS Servers' -A2`
https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-set-dns-nameservers-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Answer (score 6):

First revert everything we did in comments.

Use:

```
$ nmcli device
```

to get a status of Network manager:

```
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE        CONNECTION 
enp3s0  ethernet  connected    myConnection
```

So my interface is `enp3s0` and my connection name is `myConnection`.

I can check what DNS server my connection is using:

```
$ nmcli -f IP4.DNS connection show myConnection
```

For you I guess it's going to show:

```
ipv4.dns:                               127.0.0.1
```

Now let's set you desired DNS serves:

```
nmcli connection modify myConnecion ipv4.dns "8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4"
```

After all reload the connection:

```
nmcli connection down myConnecion
nmcli connection up myConnecion
```

Then check `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

If it still says that you are using `127.0.0.1` as your DNS server then there is a high chance you're using "dnsmasq", to make sure run:

```
sudo ss -pln sport = 53
```

You should get `dnsmasq` name as a process listening on port 53, so every thing is fine and you are using correct DNS name serves, 127.0.0.1 is just a layer between you and the servers you set.

If you want to actually see "8.8.8.8" in `/etc/resolv.conf` then you should disable "dnsmasq".

Open this file :

```
/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

Change `dns=dnsmasq` to `#dns=dnsmasq`.

Finally:

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

Now check `/etc/resolv.conf` again.